# Oracle SQL: Merging multiple columns into 1 with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and don't really have a lot of experience. I need help on this where I have Table A and I want to write a SQL query to generate the result. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Table A

| Name | Capacity A | Capacity B | Capacity C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plant 1 | 10 |  | 20 |
| Plant 2 |  | 10 |  |

Result Table

| Name | Type | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plant 1 | A,C | 10,20 |
| Plant 2 | B | 10 |

I know listagg function might be able to combine few columns into one, but is there anyway for me to generate the additional column 'Type' where its smart enough to know which column I am taking my value from? Preferably without creating any additional views/table.

Comment: You probably should rethink your table design.

Comment: I wish I have the power to change the structure of the database. Haha. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NVL2` (or `CASE`) and concatenate the columns and trim any excess trailing commas:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       RTRIM(
         NVL2(CapacityA,'A,',NULL)
         ||NVL2(CapacityB,'B,',NULL)
         ||NVL2(CapacityC,'C',NULL),
         ','
       ) AS type,
       RTRIM(
         NVL2(CapacityA,CapacityA||',',NULL)
         ||NVL2(CapacityB,CapacityB||',',NULL)
         ||NVL2(CapacityC,CapacityC,NULL),
         ','
       ) AS capacity
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, capacitya, capacityb, capacityc) AS
SELECT 'Plant1', 10, NULL, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Plant2', NULL, 10, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | TYPE | CAPACITY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Plant1 | A,C | 10,20 |
> | Plant2 | B | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a505b7a1a609246c135c0d8b86b3c35)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

- sample data in lines #1 - 4
- `temp` CTE simply - conditionally - concatenates types and capacities
- final query (line #17)

  - removes double separators (commas) (regexp)
  - removes superfluous leading/trailing commas (trim)

---

```
SQL> with test (name, capa, capb, capc) as
  2    (select 'Plant1', 10, null, 20 from dual union all
  3     select 'Plant2', null, 10, null from dual
  4    ),
  5  temp as
  6    (select name,
  7      --
  8      case when capa is not null then 'A' end ||','||
  9      case when capb is not null then 'B' end ||','||
 10      case when capc is not null then 'C' end as type,
 11      --
 12      case when capa is not null then capa end ||','||
 13      case when capb is not null then capb end ||','||
 14      case when capc is not null then capc end as capacity
 15    from test
 16    )
 17  select name,
 18    trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(type    , ',+', ',')) as type,
 19    trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(capacity, ',+', ',')) as capacity
 20  from temp;

NAME   TYPE       CAPACITY
------ ---------- ----------
Plant1 A,C        10,20
Plant2 B          10

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. This solution works as well! But the other guy's solution was slightly simpler because there is no need to create an additional temporary view.